# increment value of form value when using click

Tags: jquery

i am trying to increase value of input field use jquery onClick

```
 <input type="hidden" name="endFrom" value="17">
 $('.ajaxRequest').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();  
     var endFrom = parseInt($('Form input[name="endFrom"]').val(), 10) + 8;     
 });
```

the above value did not increment the endFrom . it simply returned the number 17

i also tried the below but that just returned 178

```
var endFrom =  $('Form input[name="endFrom"]').val()+ 8 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual code you are just concatenating two strings if you do :

```
var endFrom =  $('Form input[name="endFrom"]').val()+ 8 ;
```

You should parse it as a number then increment it:

```
var endFrom =  parseInt($('Form input[name="endFrom"]').val(), 10)+ 8 ;
```

**And it will return `25` instead of `178`.**

```js
$('.ajaxRequest').click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  var endFrom = parseInt($('input[name="endFrom"]').val(), 10) + 8;
  alert(endFrom);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Increment" class="ajaxRequest" />

<input type="hidden" name="endFrom" value="17">
```

## EDIT:

And to change the value of the input with every increment you just need to change this:

```
var endFrom = parseInt($('input[name="endFrom"]').val(), 10) + 8;
```

With the following:

```
$('input[name="endFrom"]').val(parseInt($('input[name="endFrom"]').val(), 10) + 8);
```

Comment: that is exactly what i did. i used parseInt but it did not increment the value

Comment: @PaulKendal See the sniippet DEMO in my answer it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function with **[`val(func)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)** , in your case it will not update it just get the value of that input tag

```js
$('.ajaxRequest').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('Form input[name="endFrom"]').val(function(i, v) {
    return parseInt(v, 10) + 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="endFrom" value="17">
  <input type="hidden" name="startFrom" value="17">
  <button class="ajaxRequest">Button</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value back to the input field

```js
$('.ajaxRequest').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var endFrom = parseInt($('Form input[name="startFrom"]').val(), 10) + 8;

  //assign the value back to the input
  $('Form input[name="endFrom"]').val(endFrom)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="startFrom" value="7" />
  <input type="hidden" name="endFrom" value="17" />
  <button class="ajaxRequest">S</button>
</form>
```

Comment: hi Arun. it does not work. the values do not increment . i also tried your jfiddle but they dont increment

Comment: @PaulKendal which values do you want to increment.... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f3tj2jjs/ - if you see the endFrom is getting updated

Comment: hey Arun. i am not sure how to use your jfiddle. i pressed the S button but cannot see any increment

Answer (score 0):

in your provided HTML the name attribute is `endForm` but in your selector is `startForm` `$('Form input[name="startFrom"]')` - also, type `form` with a lower case.

you just save the calculated value in a var, but you dont apply that var's value in the input afterwards:

```
$('.ajaxRequest').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();  
  var endFrom = parseInt($('form input[name="startFrom"]').val(), 10) + 8;
  $('form input[name="endFrom"]').val(endFrom);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Read the startFrom value.

`$('Form input[name="startFrom"]').val()`

Step 2 - Convert it to INT.

`parseInt($('Form input[name="startFrom"]').val())`

Step 3 - Add 8 to the number.

`parseInt($('Form input[name="startFrom"]').val()) + 8`

Step 4 - Set endForm value to the result of step 3.

`$('Form input[name="endFrom"]').val(parseInt($('Form input[name="startFrom"]').val()) + 8)`